# File path for Sparsitiy Sparksee file/database

Tags: android, file-io

I am using Sparksee database, which requires to provide a path for the database file. Comparing it with sqlite, I simply wrote the filename without any path.

```
try 
   { gdb = sparksee.create("filepath", "alias"); } 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   { e.printStackTrace(); }
```

It gives an FileNotFoundException on running.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File cannot be created
```

The documentation/API does not specify any special path requirements, it simply says to provide a path for the file. I tried using the default database path :

```
/data/data/com.example.sparksee/databases/file
```

But it does not work as well.

What path should be provided in such a scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used this code to get a file path :

```
in Activity : 
String path = this.getFileDirs().getPath();

in DatabaseCode :
gdb = sparksee.create(path + "/filepath", "alias");
```

The file was created in the `/data/data/package/file/` folder. The application ran perfectly well without any hiccups.